# Differentiate between Solution build and Project build in project file

Tags: msbuild

I've been trying to spawn a shell only if I build the project directly not on a solution build.
The command that spawns the shell is:

```
  <Target Name="TypeScriptBuild" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
        <TypeScriptCompile Remove="ts\**\*.ts" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Exec Command="npm i" />
    <Exec Command="npm run build" ConsoleToMsBuild="True" />
    <Exec Command="powershell start-process 'npm' -ArgumentList 'run','watch'" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" />
  </Target>
```

But if I get a solution build instead of a project build, this shell spawns anyways which makes perfect sense. I need to add a new Condition which checks if this is a solution build not a project build.

**What I want is the property which identifies the solution build.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a set of properties will have values in a project if a solution is built which builds the project and will not have values if the project is built directly.

The set includes:

- `SolutionFileName`
- `SolutionName`

Detecting a 'solution build' might look like:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IsSolutionBuild>False</IsSolutionBuild>
    <IsSolutionBuild Condition="'$(SolutionName)' != ''">True</IsSolutionBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

By design, `IsSolutionBuild` will be either `true` or `false`.

The `IsSolutionBuild` property can be used in a condition on your target.

Example:

```xml
  <Target Name="TypeScriptBuild" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition="!$(IsSolutionBuild)">
```